# I keep getting 'No class was registered (through reference chain: ... )' , but I registered my entites

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am writing my food delivery application on Google App Engine.
I have two working entities (class) : **Menu** and **Profile** and their endpoints classes. It works perfectly.
I added a third entity: **Order**, it looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
@Id
public Long id;
@Load
public Ref<Profile> profile;
@Load
public Ref<Menu> menu;

public Order() {}

public Long getId() { return id; }
public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}
public Profile getProfile() { return profile.get(); }
public void setProfile(Profile profile) { this.profile = Ref.create(profile);}
public Menu getMenu() {return menu.get();}
public void setMenu(Menu menu) { this.menu = Ref.create(menu); }
}
```

And I have an OfyService class where all my entities are registered:

```
public class OfyService {

static {
ObjectifyService.register(Menu.class);
ObjectifyService.register(Profile.class);
ObjectifyService.register(Order.class);
}

public static Objectify ofy() {
return ObjectifyService.ofy();
}

public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
return ObjectifyService.factory();
}
}
```

I call this static ofy() method in every endpoint class but I'm still getting error on the Api Explorer. It says:

```
 "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:  No class 'hu.iit.bme.api.model.Menu' was registered (through reference chain: hu.iit.bme.api.model.Order[\"menu\"])
```

Any idea? What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jirungaray's answer is probably the root of the matter - it's easy to accidentally import the wrong `ofy()` method and miss out on the static initializer block.

I'm changing my opinion about whether registering classes this way is a best practice. This issue comes up too much.

The important thing is that classes should be registered in a single thread before your application starts. There are a number of ways you can guarantee this without having to resort to static initializer blocks. The most reliable is to move your registration into a `ServletContextListener` registered in `web.xml`.

I will update the Objectify docs with this recommendation soon.

Answer (score 3):

@stickfigure is right. I was getting the error even though I had registered it as @Sappy did.

What I did was to create a class OfyHelper and registered in the web.xml

```
public class OfyHelper implements ServletContextListener {
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // This will be invoked as part of a warmup request, or the first user request if no warmup
    // request.
    ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(BeerBrand.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(BeerStyle.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(BeerBottle.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(BeerCategory.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(Beer.class);
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // App Engine does not currently invoke this method.
}
```

and in the web.xml to insert:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>br.com.jluiz.myPackage.OfyHelper</listener-class>
</listener>
```

you can get more help here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `import static com.yourcode.OfyService.ofy;` and not `import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy` on your endpoints.

EDIT:
As per [Objectify docs](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices) you should register your entities like this:

```
static {
        factory().register(Thing.class);
        factory().register(OtherThing.class);
    }
```

Seems like you are not getting your entities registered on the factory which will later spawn your service.

Comment: I use everywhere : `import static hu.iit.bme.api.OfyService.ofy;`

Comment: hmmm that's weird... could you please include your endpoints code?

Comment: Sure, https://gist.github.com/mpxr/5b13ed2f2f6b9c3adbcf (insert method)
I'm still using the auto-generated code, but I think it should work.

Comment: everything seems to check out. if you have the time please give this a try: create a servlet, set in to <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> on your web.xml and override it's init method. within that method register your classes using ObjectifyService.register(Order.class);